# Real Analysis Proof of Upper Bound

Tags: real-analysis

It's been a while since I have done any analysis based proofs, and I find myself struggling a good bit. Any detailed help (or examples) would be appreciated.

I am given the following facts:

1) For every sequence of points in $[a,b]$ there exists a convergent subsequence.

2) $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if for every convergent sequence of points $x_i$ in $[a,b]$

$$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} f(x_i) = f(\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} x_i)$$

3) Given a bounded set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if $s=\sup(S)$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x$ in $S$ such that $x > s-\epsilon$

It is given that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

I am asked to show that...

**a)** $f$ is bounded above (there exists $K$ in $\mathbb{R}$ st for every $x$ in $[a,b]$, $f(x)<K$)

From the hint below, I have updated my approach at this proof:

Assume that $f$ is not bounded above, that is there exists $x_n\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{R}$. As $x_n\in[a,b]$ we know $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence (fact 1), and let us say that it converges to $x$.

**I am not sure how to get from this point, to the eventual contradiction...**

Now choose $K\in \mathbb{R}$ st $f(x)<K$. From fact 2 we know

$$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} x_n) = f(x)<K$$

But we assumed $f(x_n)>n$ for all n, so we have a contradiction.

**b)** $f$ attains its maximum on $[a,b]$

Haven't started on this one, due to being stuck on the first still.

Comment: Good hints so far, but for (b), I think this is an application of Heine-Borel.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Just work directly with the convergent subsequence, call it $x_{n_k}$. The key is that it converges to some $x$, and $f$ is continuous so $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(x)$. Now recall how we defined the sequence $x_n$ to see why this is a contradiction.

Comment: Would it be the fact that $f(x)$ equals some constant, $c$, and there exists $n \in N$ such that $n > c$, so eventually we will reach a $n$ such that $f(x_n)\leq n$...? Not sure how I would put that in notation, but it seems to make sense.

Comment: $f(x)$ equals some constant $c$, whereas $f(x_{n_k}) > n_k \geq k$ by the way the sequence was constructed. This means that $f(x_{n_k})$ increases to infinity, so it certainly can't converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and helps clarify what I was thinking was going on. Thank you so much for all the help on this.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to update your post with any progress on (b) and I'll give you more hints if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated hint for (a): so we have a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) > n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence, call it $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x$. Since $f$ is continuous, we must have $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = f(x)$. Why is this a contradiction?

---

Hint for (b): by part (a), $f$ is bounded above, so $\{f(x) : x \in [a,b]\}$ has a least upper bound (supremum), call it $M$. Show that there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \rightarrow M$. Now use the fact that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Would this be correct?

Assume that $f$ is not bounded above, that is there exists $x_i \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_i)>n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{R}$. As $x_n \in [a,b]$ we know $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence (fact 1), and let us say that it converges to $x$. As $x_n$ has a subsequence that converges to $x$, $x_n$ itself converges to $x$ (proof provided). So $x_n \rightarrow x$. Now choose $K \in \mathbb(R)$ st $f(x)<K$. From fact 2 we know

$$\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} f(x_i) = f(\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} x_i) = f(x) < K$$

But we assumed $f(x_n) > n$ for all n, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: @user3784030: First, I think you want to say there exists $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n) > n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{R}$. The way you wrote it, there's no connection between $i$ and $n$. Second, it is *not* true that the existence of a subsequence of $x_n$ converging to $x$ implies that $x_n$ itself converges to $x$. Indeed, $x_n$ itself may not converge. But that doesn't matter, you only need the subsequence. Also, please edit your original post with any progress so the math won't all be buried in the comments.

Comment: Yup, the two $i$ in the beginning were typos. I guess I am just confused how to go from "$x_n$ has a subsequence that converges to $x$" to showing the contradiction that you can choose a $K$ st $f(x)<K$. I will update my main post right now as well - thanks for the help so far, it's been almost 4 years since I have done any analysis, so I am trying to get back into the swing of it.